# Responsive images for a mobile website that scales with the same width and height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a bit stuck with my meager css skills. I have a bootstrap panel and a grid layout that contains 3 images in a single row.

My problem is that the images that I get from the webservice are all very different in size. some are HD quality and others are 80 X 80 pixels. I want to use css and make all three images appear the same size. The images must also be responsive since this is a mobile website. I found a solution that does what I want, but the stock browser on android does not support vw and vh. My current solution is as follows.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center"><span class="colorText greenText21">Photo Gallery</span></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                <img src="Images/c1.png" style="width: 21vw; height: 18vw" alt="Image" class="text-center" id="gallery_Image1" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                <img src="Images/c2.png" style="width: 21vw; height: 18vw; " alt="Image" class="text-center" id="gallery_Image2" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                <img src="Images/c3.png" style="width: 21vw; height: 18vw; " alt="Image" class="text-center" id="gallery_Image3" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Is there a easy css cross browser solution that will allow me to get all three images to be the same size, whilst also being responsive ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this *class* on your img tag

```
.img-responsive
```

### Boostrap 3 - Responsive images

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Is is almost important (but not fundamental) that aspect ratio of different images is the same.

Anyway, use % instead of "vw", setting width to '100%' and height to 'auto' for IMG tags. They will be contain inside 'col-xs-4' containers.

Comment: Using 100% and auto does get me close. The width is then perfect, but this again leaves me with another problem. The aspect ratios of the images are also different, leaving the heights of each picture as different. I tried this before posting. But thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: The images should scale to be a rectangle of a precise aspect ratio, regardless of current aspect ratio. Letting the image maintain it's current aspect ratio is.

Comment: mhmmmm I don't understand without a mockup or an example in jsfiddle....
If aspect ratio is fixed and does not be dependent by original one, you should calculate % of height comparing to width, for which you have the desired aspect ratio, and set it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with twitter bootstrap not to long ago. I used this method as supplied by another users jsfiddle. It centers images of different sizes in a responsive container. I would still try to use PHP or some other server side code to resize images to a smaller size so you are not resizing a 3000px image down to 80px for example.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/46psK/4/)

.html

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="centerer"></div>
        <img src="/path/to/image" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.dummy {
    padding-top: 100%; /* forces 1:1 aspect ratio */
}

.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    text-align:center; /* Align center inline elements */
    font: 0/0 a;
}

.img-container .centerer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;  /* <-- Set maximum height to 100% of its parent */
    max-width: 100%;   /* <-- Set maximum width to 100% of its parent */
}
```

Comment: I think I might be missing something else. It scales a bit better than what I had. and it is a very nice solution, but it still doesn't force a 1:1 aspect ratio. But thank you for your response. Is there anything that I could try checking ?

Comment: It becomes more complicated if you have vertical and landscape images to force the 1x1. You could set the image container to a specific height and then set overflow:hidden on the image container this would cut off images as the page scaled to fit in the box. I might suggest a jquery option for ease of use. http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php It would scale all images to a specific width, I would set it large like 300x300 and then add a class of full-width, and in css make `.full-width { width: 100% }`